# Passing a filepath to fopen from an Array Fails in C

Tags: c

I have a two filepaths input by the user and stored in an array.  However, when I try to use one of these filepaths to open a file using fopen the code exits as if the file does not exist.  If I hard code the filepath into the fopen function eveything proceeds perfectly.

For Example:

```
//Libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

//Global Functions

//Main Function
int main()
{

    //Local Variables
    char * user_input_full = NULL;
    char user_input = 'a';
    size_t len = 0;         //Pointer for user_input_full
    int size = 0;           //Length of the input_use_full array
    char *input_array[2];       //This hold the filepaths
    int i=0;            //A loop counter

    //Carve out an initial array for the use input string (it is of unknown length)
    user_input_full = calloc(16,sizeof(char));
    size = 16;

    //Take user input until a newline is encountered.
    while(user_input != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c", &user_input);

        user_input_full[len] = user_input;
        len = len+1;
        if(len==size)
        {
            #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
            printf("The input stream is being reallocated\n");
            #endif
            user_input_full = realloc(user_input_full,sizeof(char)*(size+16));
            if(user_input_full == NULL)
            {
                //realloc failed, return a fail status
                printf("Realloc of the input stream failed.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }

    user_input_full[len] = '\0';

    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    printf("The user input was: %s \n", user_input_full);
    #endif

    //Parse out the file streams
    input_array[i] = strtok(user_input_full," ");

    while(input_array[i]!=NULL)
    {
        input_array[++i] = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    printf("Input array Values:\n");
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n",input_array[i]);
    }
    #endif

    //open the file specified in input_array[0]
    if(fopen(input_array[0],"r") == NULL)
    {
        printf("Open of the input file failed.\n");
        printf("Tried to open: %s ", input_array[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
          printf("The file opened.\n");
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Would print the error block.  However:

```
//Open the file specified in array[0]
if(fopen("test.txt","r") == NULL)
{
     printf("Failed to open the input file.\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
else
{
     printf("The file opened.\n");
}
```

Works perfectly fine.

I also tried passing the value in input_array[0] to a const char*, but that did not work either.  I feel like I am missing some fundamental concept here.

EDIT: Clarified one of the comments in the code block

Comment: Did you check the values of the strings in the array? Are they what they should be?

Comment: [Please post a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You don't show how you fill in your array, for instance.

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Comment: show the code that populates the array

Comment: The first example, as given, has undefined behavior on account of the array elements not having been initialized.

Comment: I have added the full block of code that fills in the array, as requested.  I have verified that the array prints out the correct character string that is input by the user.  If I input "test.txt something", than array[0] = test.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason it is failing is due to trailing newline in the filename. All you need is to add newline as string token.

Change this line:

```
input_array[i] = strtok(user_input_full," ");
```

to:

```
input_array[i] = strtok(user_input_full," \n");
```

and this line:

```
input_array[++i] = strtok(NULL," ");
```

to:

```
input_array[++i] = strtok(NULL," \n");
```

This will remove the trailing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake I note is in the following code block. it's inputing 3 three strings to `input_array` and going out of bound.

```
//Parse out the file streams
input_array[i] = strtok(user_input_full," ");

while(input_array[i]!=NULL)
{
    input_array[++i] = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Change this code block to something as shown here.

```
input_array[i] = strtok(user_input_full," ");
for(i=1;i<2;i++)
{
    input_array[i] = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Comment: I am using strtok to input the values to input_array.  I added all of my code above.

Comment: @Confused_Engineer: Ohk, Let me check that.

Comment: I have part of it figured out.  If the second filepath is left empty (something that the user can do), than fopen fails.  I am not sure why this is though.

Comment: Following code block is assigning 3 strings to input_array and goind out of bound (not correct) //Parse out the file streams
    input_array[i] = strtok(user_input_full," ");

    while(input_array[i]!=NULL)
    {
        input_array[++i] = strtok(NULL," ");
    }

Comment: How is it doing that?  My understanding is the first strtok parses out the first filepath into input_array[0] and the second strtok should parse out the second into input_array[1] (if it exists).  Apparently this is incorrect?

Comment: @Confused_Engineer:  input_array[0] = firstfile , input_array[1] = second, input_array[2] = <null> which is out of bound. Put a 'printf' inside while loop and you will figure it out.

Comment: @Confused_Engineer - when user only puts one filename, the filename contains `\n`. But if you remove/replace `'\n'` with `'\0'` or `' '`, it will work.

Comment: @alvits - Thanks.  That was the root of the issue.

Comment: @nitin - I see it now.  Thanks.